# angular ui bootstrap datepicker parsing not working properly

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-datepicker

I am using angular-ui-bootstrap datepicker. When i try to change the date manually in input box as 1/1/2015 then the model value is undefined But when I enter as 01/01/2015 it works fine.

I want to use both the format.

`Plunkr link:` [Demo link](http://plnkr.co/edit/mnP88IlRP4BevHfDCjfc?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

I see the issue, here is something I found as a fix:

```
app = angular.module 'myapp', ['ng-bootstrap-datepicker']

AppCtrl = ($scope)->
  $scope.datepickerOptions =
    format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'
    language: 'fr'
    autoclose: true
    weekStart: 0

  $scope.date = '12-03-2000'

app.controller 'AppCtrl', AppCtrl    
angular.bootstrap document, ['myapp']
```

Check out this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/cletourneau/kGGCZ/

This allows for both formats to be accepted, change the scope date and the date picker should work

Comment: here you are using 'ng-bootstrap-datepicker' library. Due to some constraints I cannot use this library. Need a  solution using the angular 'ui.bootstrap' library